# Concurrency problems from eager materialization?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, concurrency

Using PostgreSQL 9.6.5, I am moving away from the built-in `MATERIALIZED VIEW` model because it lacks incremental refresh, and for my purposes (replication through SymmetricDS) I actually need the data in table storage, not view. My solution:

1. Create an "unmaterialized view" `VIEW_XXX_UNMAT` (really just a select)
2. Create table `VIEW_XXX` as select from `VIEW_XXX_UNMAT` (snapshot)
3. Add primary key to `VIEW_XXX`
4. Create a refresh function which deletes from and reinserts into `VIEW_XXX` based on the primary key
5. Create `INSERT`/`DELETE`/`UPDATE` triggers for each table involved in `VIEW_XXX_UNMAT`, which call the refresh function with the appropriate PK

My inspiration comes from this [PGCon 2008](https://www.pgcon.org/2008/schedule/track/Tutorial/69.en.html) talk and once we get over the hurdle of creating all these triggers it all works nicely. Obviously we are limiting the `UPDATE` triggers to the columns that are involved, and only refreshing the view if `NEW` data is distinct from `OLD` data.

At this point I'd like to know:

1. If there are any better solutions out there (extension?) keeping in mind that I need tables in the end
2. Performance issues (I understand the refresh cost is write-bound, but because the materialized table is indexed, it's pretty fast?)
3. Concurrency issues (what if two people are updating the same field at the same time, which refreshes the materialized view through triggers, will one of them fail or will MVCC "take care of it"?)